# Wordpress shortcode function adding wrapping everything in <p> markup

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I am facing an issue with creating a shortcode in my functions.php file, it seems it works and pulls the data set in the shortcode but within the function it sets some javascript and html however it is adding

on everything and breaking the JS any ideas?

Error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid property id
[Break On This Error]   

key: '#$7bbad3b0fdd52cc4277',</p>
```

Code:

```
// Set Video URL and Subtitle URL
 // shortcode [video]
function show_video( $atts ){
   $video_details="";
   // get attibutes and set defaults
            extract(shortcode_atts(array(
                            'file' => '',
                            'cc' => ''
         ), $atts));
    // Display info 

        $video_details="

        <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"flowplayer-3.2.6.min.js\"></script>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"flowplayer.ipad-3.2.2.min.js\"></script>

    <!-- player container-->
    <a href=\"".$file."\" style=\"display:block;width:473px;height:310px;\" id=\"ipad\"></a>

    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
    $f(\"ipad\", \"flowplayer.commercial-3.2.7.swf\",{
      // commercial version requires product key
      key: '#$7bbad3b0fdd52cc4277',

      // now we can tweak the logo settings
      logo: {
        url:'logo.png',
        opacity: 0.6,
        top: 10,
        left: 15,
        fullscreenOnly: false,
        linkUrl: 'http://www.domain.com/'
      },
      contextMenu: ['Media Player 1.0'],
      clip: {
        autoPlay: false,
        url: '".$file."',

        // this is the Timed Text file with captions info
        captionUrl: '".$cc."'
      },
      /* playlist: [
          // 1:st clip
          {
            url: '".$file."',
            customProperties: {
              related: 'related.txt'
            }
          },
      ], */
      plugins:  {

        captions: {
          url: 'flowplayer.captions-3.2.3.swf',

          // pointer to a content plugin (see below)
          captionTarget: 'content'
        },

      /*related: {
          url:'flowplayer.commercial-3.2.7.swf',
          related: 'related.txt',        
          width: 400
      },*/

        // configure a content plugin to look good for our purpose
        content: {
          url:'flowplayer.content-3.2.0.swf',
          bottom: 25,
          width: '80%',
          height:40,
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          backgroundGradient: 'none',
          borderRadius: 4,
          border: 0,
          textDecoration: 'outline',
          style: {
            body: {
              fontSize: 14,
              fontFamily: 'Arial',
              textAlign: 'center',
              color: '#ffffff'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }).ipad();
    </script>
        ";
        return $video_details;
}
//add our shortcode movie
add_shortcode('video', 'show_video');
```

Some of the Output:

```
<p>     <script type="text/javascript" src="flowplayer-3.2.6.min.js"></script><br />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="flowplayer.ipad-3.2.2.min.js"></script></p>
<p>    <!-- player container--><br />
    <a href="" style="display:block;width:473px;height:310px;" id="ipad"></a></p>
<p>    <script type="text/javascript">
    ("ipad", "flowplayer.commercial-3.2.7.swf",{
      // commercial version requires product key
      key: '#$7bbad3b0fdd52cc4277',</p>
<p>      // now we can tweak the logo settings
      logo: {
        url:'logo.png',
        opacity: 0.6,
        top: 10,
        left: 15,
        fullscreenOnly: false,
        linkUrl: 'http://www.domain.com/'
      },
      contextMenu: ['Media Player 1.0'],
      clip: {
        autoPlay: false,
        url: '',</p>
```

Comment: No one have a solution? i have tried many from looking online but nothing seems to work

Comment: Anyone? i have to deliver this project tomorrow (sunday, yes working sunday) as its being done as a demo to the mayor of london monday.....

Answer (score 0):

To deal with the [wpautop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) issue in your shortcode output you could, as suggested [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/55783/25765), put the following at the end of your `functions.php` file:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' , 99 );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop', 100 );
```

Comment: I have tried that, i added that after the add_shortcode but does not seem to do anything

Comment: I have done a lot of research online and seen many solutions including the one you stated above but again failed, let me check teh framework in case it is not ,99

Comment: i really need to sort this tonight, deadline at weekend and this is holding me back on content, would really be good if someone could help sort this issue. Thanks

Comment: You could put the script in a separate file and enqueue it in the shortcode callback function (same for the flowplayer scripts). You can get and use the shortcode variables by localizing your script with `wp_localize_script`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Comment: I am not that good at all this, could you help me out with it?